# SQL Select Sub Query for Value subtraction

Tags: mysql

I have some MYSQL tables related to vehicle management. Table "tbl_vehicle" includes vehicle data and Table "tbl_fuel" includes fuel data and then table "tbl_fuel_issue" includes fuel issuing data as follows.

## tbl_vehicle

```
+------------+------------+
| vehicle_id | vehicle_no |
+------------+------------+
|          1 | V1         |
|          2 | V2         |
|          3 | V3         |
|          4 | V4         |
|          5 | V5         |
+------------+------------+
```

## tbl_fuel

```
+---------+--------+
| fuel_id |  fuel  |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | Diesel |
|       2 | Petrol |
+---------+--------+
```

## tbl_fuel_issue

```
+----------------+---------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+
| fuel__issue_id | vehicle | fuel | qty | issue_date | order_no | milo_meter |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+
|              1 |       1 |    1 |  20 | 2019-07-02 |   172200 |      20450 |
|              2 |       1 |    1 |  25 | 2019-07-10 |   172201 |      20600 |
|              3 |       4 |    2 |  10 | 2019-08-06 |   172202 |      45222 |
|              4 |       1 |    1 |  30 | 2019-08-08 |   172203 |      21000 |
|              5 |       2 |    1 |  12 | 2019-08-22 |   172204 |      10450 |
|              6 |       2 |    1 |  12 | 2019-08-25 |   172205 |      10600 |
+----------------+---------+------+-----+------------+----------+------------+
```

Then I need to get fuel consumption of selected vehicle in a selected time frame as a desired output like this:

## Desired Output

```
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| vehicle_no |       duration        | consumption |
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| V1         | 2019-07-02-2019-08-08 |        7.33 |
+------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

Tried to get desired out put using SQL Statement

```
SELECT tbl_vehicle.vehicle_no, t1.qty, (SELECT t2.milo_meter-t1.milo_meter/t2.qty AS consumption FROM tbl_fuel_issue t2) FROM tbl_fuel_issue t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_vehicle ON tbl_vehicle.vehicle_id = t1.vehicle
LEFT JOIN tbl_fuel ON tbl_fuel.fuel_id = t1.fuel
WHERE issue_date BETWEEN '2019-07-02' AND '2019-08-08' AND tbl_vehicle.vehicle_no='V1'
```

Note - Fuel consumption is calculated for this question by using the following formula.

t2.milo_meter - t1.milo_meter / sum(t2.qty) 
=21000-20450/75 
=7.33

But did not get the desired output. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih. See the edited question

Comment: I left how to solve the problem and trying how did you get 7.33 from you data? Could you Illustrate more on this table only tbl_fuel_issue by V1 only?

Comment: @ Adam. See the MJoy's Answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `MIN` & `MAX` fn to get the start and end distance and group it across various vehicle_no. The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT tbl_vehicle.vehicle_no
    ,CAST(MIN(issue_date) AS CHAR(10))+' '+CAST(MAX(issue_date) AS CHAR(10)) AS duration
    ,(MAX(t1.milo_meter)-MIN(t1.milo_meter)) / SUM(t1.qty) AS consumption
FROM tbl_fuel_issue t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl_vehicle ON tbl_vehicle.vehicle_id = t1.vehicle
LEFT JOIN tbl_fuel ON tbl_fuel.fuel_id = t1.fuel
WHERE issue_date BETWEEN '2019-07-02' AND '2019-08-08'
GROUP BY tbl_vehicle.vehicle_no
```